# Qt Menu with QLinEdit action

Tags: qt

I want to have a line edit field in a popup menu I've got.  I'm basically letting the user pick from one of several common sizes for something, but I want them to be able to enter a custom size as the last entry in the menu.

So I've got something like this (snipped from larger code, new_menu is the menu of interest):

```
QWidget     *widget = new QWidget(new_menu);                                 
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;                                   

QLineEdit* le = new QLineEdit;                                                      
le->setPlaceholderText("Custom");                                        
le->setFixedWidth(100);                                                  
ayout->addWidget(le);                                                   
widget->setLayout(layout);                                               

QWidgetAction* wa = new QWidgetAction(new_menu);                         
wa->setActionGroup(group);                                               
wa->setDefaultWidget(widget);                                            
new_menu->addAction(wa);                                                 

connect(le, SIGNAL(returnPressed()), this, SLOT(leslot()));
```

Which works great, the `LineEdit` shows up nice and centered in the menu, it's got the placeholder text, I can click it and edit, everything. However, when I hit enter on the `textBox`, it emits the `returnPressed` signal and the menu emits a `triggered` signal with one of the other actions on the list, so at best I'm changing my configuration twice and at worst things break.

Additionally, when I click off the edge of the `LineEdit` (still in the menu though, but not in the editable area), the menu emits a triggered signal with the `QWidgetAction` associated with it, which isn't what I want.

So two questions:
1) Can I get the return to work the way I want.  It's fine if the menu closes when it's hit, but it can't emit another action too.
2) Can I get it to not emit an action at all when the `lineEdit` is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing for anyone that follows.  I subclassed QLineEdit thusly:

```
class EnterLineEdit : public QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT
 public:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *evt) {
        if (evt->key() == Qt::Key_Enter || evt->key() == Qt::Key_Return) {
            emit returnPressed();
        } else {
            QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(evt);
        }        
    }
};
```

This lets me manually emit the returnPressed signal when enter/return is hit and *not* pass it up the widget hierarchy, so the menu never sees it when enter is hit over the lineedit.  I connected the returnPressed signal to the hide() slot of the menu so that the menu will still close, but without triggering an action.